# Using drawImage to draw a filled rectangle

Tags: drawimage

if I want to draw a filled rectangle, I could do

```
g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
```

But if I want to draw the same filled rectangle with drawImage, what do I do? I tried the below:

```
g.drawImage(null, 0,0,100, 100, Color.BLACK, null);
```

And it does not work. I am not going to use an image, but must the Image still be non-null? What would be the correct way to do this?